# AS3 Game spawn mechanics

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I am currently working on a game with a friend, and i need some help with some code... In my game i want to make balls appear on the screen, but in a specific order, so i have created lists which will decide where to spawn the balls, and what color. Example:

```
var a:Array = [["green", "red", "blue", "purple"],
               ["orange", "red", "yellow", "black"],
               ["green", "green", "blue", "pink"]]
```

The inter dimensional arrays is because of the order i want them to spawn in(starting from the bottom). I have figured out how to spawn all the balls but when they do spawn they spawn on top of each other. 
Can someone please help me with this? Thanks! (i am making it in flash btw)

code i have:

```
    import flash.events.Event;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, main);


// Variabels 

var row1:Number = 92.25;
var row2:Number = 243.30;
var row3:Number = 394.30;
var row4:Number = 547.35;

var pattern:Array = pattern1;
/*
var array:Array = pattern.reverse();
var rows:Number = pattern1.length;
*/

//trace(pattern.reverse());

//Frame counter
var frame:Number = 0;

function main(e:Event):void {
    make(pattern.reverse(), pattern.length);
    trace(pattern);
}

function make(array:Array, rows):void {
    //Count frames
    frame += 1;
    //trace(frame);


    if (frame % 30 == 0) {
        //Go thrugh the rows
        for (var r = 0; r<rows; r+=1) {
            //trace(array[r]);

            //Go thrugh the lists
            for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i+= 1) {
                spawnBall(array[r][i], i);
            }

        }
    }
    /*
    // Go through each row 
    for (var r = 0; r <= rows; r += 1) {

    }
    // Go through the list and spawn;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i+=1) {
        spawnBall(array[i], i);
    }
    */
}

// Spawn the ball
function spawnBall(color:String, pos:Number):void {

    if (color == "###") {

        trace("Not a color");

    } else {

        switch (color) {
            case "lil":
                var purple_ball:PurpleBall = new PurpleBall;
                addChild(purple_ball);  
                purple_ball.x = setX(pos);
                purple_ball.y = 0;
            break;

            case "gul":
                var yellow_ball:YellowBall = new YellowBall;
                addChild(yellow_ball);      
                yellow_ball.x = setX(pos);
                yellow_ball.y = 0;
            break;

            case "grø":
                var green_ball:GreenBall = new GreenBall;
                addChild(green_ball);
                green_ball.x = setX(pos);
                green_ball.y = 0;
            break;

            case "rød":
                var red_ball:RedBall = new RedBall;
                addChild(red_ball);
                red_ball.x = setX(pos);
                red_ball.y = 0;
            break;

            case "blå":
                var blue_ball:BlueBall = new BlueBall;
                addChild(blue_ball);
                blue_ball.x = setX(pos);
                blue_ball.y = 0;
            break;

            case "ros":
                var pink_ball:PinkBall = new PinkBall;
                addChild(pink_ball);
                pink_ball.x = setX(pos);
                pink_ball.y = 0;
            break;

            case "ora":
                var orange_ball:OrangeBall = new OrangeBall;
                addChild(orange_ball);
                orange_ball.x = setX(pos);
                orange_ball.y = 0;
            break;
        }   
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall)
    }

    function setX(pos):Number {
        var xpos:Number;

        switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                xpos = row1;
            break;

            case 1:
                xpos = row2;
            break;

            case 2:
                xpos = row3;
            break;

            case 3:
                xpos = row4;
            break;
        }

        return xpos;
    }

}


//Move the balls
function moveBall(e:Event) {
    e.currentTarget.y += 5;
}
```

[image: The Balls are on top of each other]

Comment: Post the code you have for doing the spawning, please. Hard to see what's wrong without that.

Comment: Looks like your case statements don't match up with your data (is that Danish?). I'd start by adding `default` cases and seeing if those are getting hit.

Comment: Norwegian actually... Can you give me an example? im very new to this

Comment: Sure thing. Let me write up an answer since the comment boxes don't allow code snippets and such.

Comment: pattern1 =[
     ["gul", "###", "lil", "blå"],
     ["ora", "rød", "grø", "###"],
     ["###", "###", "blå", "grø"]
     ];
This is the actual list

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier to fix this if we do some refactoring first. `setX()` is clunky, for example. There's a lot that can go wrong there. If nothing else, it can be greatly abbreviated:

```
//                     0      1       2       3
var xPositions:Array = [92.25, 243.30, 394.30, 547.35];

function setX(pos:Number):Number {
  return xPositions[pos];
}
```

`spawnBall` can be likewise simplified.

```
var ballColors:Object = {
    "lil": PurpleBall,
    "gul": YellowBall,
    "grø": GreenBall,
    "rød": RedBall,
    "blå": BlueBall,
    "ros": PinkBall,
    "ora": OrangeBall
};

function spawnBall(color:String, pos:Number):void {
    var Ball = ballColors[color];
    if (Ball == undefined) {
        trace("Not a color: " + color);
        return
    }
    var ball = new Ball();
    addChild(ball);
    ball.x = setX(pos);
    ball.y = 0;

    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);
}

//Move the balls
function moveBall(e:Event):void {
    e.currentTarget.y += 5;
}
```

Now that `spawnBall` is more manageable, we can see the problem more clearly. You're attaching the `moveBall` event handler to the stage, and then having it move the stage instead of the balls. Since you want to move all the balls simultaneously, having one event handler attached to the stage makes sense, but you need to keep the set of spawned balls in an array so you can update all of them.

Let's move the `addEventListener()` call out to the initialization logic and add a global array to store the list of balls.

`spawnBall` becomes:

```
function spawnBall(color:String, pos:Number):void {
    var Ball = ballColors[color];
    if (Ball == undefined) {
        trace("Not a color: " + color);
        return
    }
    var ball = new Ball();
    addChild(ball);
    ball.x = setX(pos);
    ball.y = 0;

    spawnedBalls.push(ball);
}
```

`moveBall` becomes:

```
//Move the balls
function moveBall(e:Event):void {
    for each (var ball in spawnedBalls) {
        ball.y -= 5;
    }
}
```

And this global variable is declared:

```
var spawnedBalls:Array = [];
```

Finally, add this to `main()`:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);
```

That should work.

Comment: Thank you! so now it spawns the balls and makes them go down every 60 frame... but it spawns the balls on top of each other. how can i make them spawn in order with a small gap between? (I want it to go through the list and spawn the first row of colors then wait a few frames before it spawns the second, and so on). i really appreciate the help! :)

Comment: Oh, so you're saying it's spawning the *rows* all at the same time, so you get one row like `o o o o` moving down the screen?

Comment: I get one row, with every ball ontop of each other, and the. It waits 60 frames before it does it again

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "every ball on top of each other." Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I put it in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79342/discussion-between-richard-knife-and-jon-molnar).